# DigestUtils.md5Hex returns the same value

Tags: java, hash, md5

Can anyone say why this Java code returns so many identical MD5 values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      String key = DigestUtils.md5Hex(rnd.nextFloat() + System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
      System.out.println(key + ", " + rnd.nextFloat() + System.currentTimeMillis() + "");
    }
  }
```

This is the output that I get:

```
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.15059251440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.599991561440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.54911111440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.0982222561440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.169987141440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.032851281440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.223390041440334190624
814788aa9b6a22bf73ff3ae5fe0c6e0c, 0.70173611440334190624
....
....
....
```

Comment: nice question for candidate interview. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my bad :)

Apparently:

```
rnd.nextFloat() + System.currentTimeMillis()
```

simply adds the 2 numbers and comes out with a very small number that is represented as the same string in Java.